# Can Dispel Magic be used on Geas?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

At the end of the Geas spell description it is stated that

> You can end the spell early by using an action to dismiss it. A remove curse, greater restoration or wish also ends it.

So the question is: is the spell Geas dispelled by Dispel Magic?

When it is casted using a spell slot of 9th level, the spell is permanent and

> lasts until it is ended by one of the spells mentioned above.

Once again, is it ended by Dispel Magic in this case?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The description of *Dispel Magic* is as follows:

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within
>   range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.
>   For each spell of 4th level or higher on the target, make
>   an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The
>   DC equals 10 + the spell’s level. On a successful check,
>   the spell ends.
>
> ***At Higher Levels.*** When you cast this spell using a
>   spell slot of 4th level or higher, you automatically end
>   the effects of a spell on the target if the spell’s level is
>   equal to or less than the level of the spell slot you used.

Note that it specifically says it can end *any* spell. *Geas* doesn't provide any exception to this; it just says that it can be ended by the spells you listed. Compare it to, for example, *Forcecage*, which includes the following line:

> This spell can't be dispelled by *dispel magic*.

If *Geas* was meant to be impossible to dispel with *Dispel Magic*, it would include a similar line.

Comment: Jeremy Crawford also agrees [here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/805820448315318272)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Dispel Magic can dispel any spell unless something specifies otherwise. Indeed, if any spell or game rule says you can do something, can always do that thing unless explicitly noted otherwise.

The spells listed in the description for Geas are not exhaustive, but rather are listed for the reader's convenience, and because it might be unclear whether a Geas is considered a "curse", which both Greater Restoration and Remove Curse are capable of removing.

In any case, unless the description says that ONLY those spells may remove a Geas, you can assume that Dispel Magic can dispel it.